# How to write single sub id field in spring mongodb aggregation

Tags: aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to get following query from Spring Data Mongo Aggregation:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "year": "$_id.year"
  },
  "result": {
    "$push": {
      "rs": "$_id.rs",
      "vl": "$vl"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried following:

```
GroupAggregation as = group( "_id.year" ).push( new BasicDBObject( "rs", "$_id.rs" ).append( "vl", "$vl" ) ).as( "result" );
```

But it generates this expression where there is no sub field "year" under "_id" field:

```
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$_id.year" , "result" : { "$push" : { "rs" : "$_id.rs" , "vl" : "$vl"}}}}
```

Any ideas on how to get that query using spring data mongodb aggregation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any hook in the api to access the previous `_id` value.

You can use `AggregationOperation` to create `$group` stage using mongodb types.

Something like

```
AggregationOperation group = new AggregationOperation() {
       @Override
       public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
          return new BasicDBObject("$group", new BasicDBObject("_id", new BasicDBObject("year", "$_id.year" )).append("result", new BasicDBObject("$push", new BasicDBObject( "rs", "$_id.rs" ).append( "vl", "$vl" ))));
    } 
};
```

Comment: As you said, there seems to be no way to do it in pure spring data mongodb. You workaround is working.