# Spring Data Mongo - Custom AggregationOperation not working

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to create an Aggregation in Spring data mongo. I am successfully able to create using OOB AggretionOperation implementations such as Lookup, Unwind etc.

However, when I try to create one using a custom AggregationOperation it gives PropertyReferenceException on lookup - "as" property item doesnt exist on the document type.

```
AggregationOperation lookup = new AggregationOperation(){ 
     @Override 
     public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext aoc) {
        return new Document("$lookup",new Document().parse("{ 'from' : 'items', 'localField' : 'item_id', 'foreignField' : '_id', 'as' : 'item'} "));
     }
};
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(match(createCriteriaForRetrievingTimeSheets(queryParams)),
        lookup,
        ....
return aggregation;
```

Comment: hey @farhan i think this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44329740/9450155) is worked.